# Automatic colouring/strikethrough in html/css?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have this (very messy) bookings.jsp file that displays different bookings and their attributes. My question is, is there anyway I could modify the .jsp file so that it changes colour/strikethrough depending on the values of the attributes. For example, every Booking object has a boolean "deleted". Is there a way to set all the Booking objects which have "deleted"=true to have a strikethrough?

Here is my bookings.jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<jsp:include page="../fragments/head.jsp"/>
<body>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/menu.jsp"/>
<div id="body">

    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">


        <h2>List of bookings</h2>

        <p>
            <a href="/restaurant/create">Add restaurant</a>
            <a href="/booking/create">Create New Booking</a>
        </p>
        <table class="">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Booking information
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${restaurants}" var="restaurants">
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>${restaurants}</h3></td>
                    <td valign="bottom"><a href="/restaurant/edit/${restaurants.id}">Edit restaurant</a></td>

                    <tr>
                        <table class="myTable">
                            <col align="left" width="110">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="90">
                            <col align="left" width="90">
                            <col align="left" width="90">
                            <col align="left" width="110">
                            <col align="left" width="100">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><b>Date</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Start</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Duration</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b># Of People</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Name</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Contact Pref.</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Phone #</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Comments</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Booking date</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Edited</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <c:forEach items="${sortedBooking}" var="sortedBooking">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${restaurants == sortedBooking.restaurant.restaurantName}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.date}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.start}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.duration}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.amountOfPeople}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.name}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.contactPreference}</td>
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${sortedBooking.phoneNumber.equals('')}">
                                                    <td>NO PHONE</td>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <td>${sortedBooking.phoneNumber}</td>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${sortedBooking.comments.equals('')}">
                                                    <td>NO COMMENTS</td>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <td>${sortedBooking.comments}</td>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.currentDatetime}</td>
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${sortedBooking.currentDatetime.equals(sortedBooking.newDate)}">
                                                    <td align="middle">-</td>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <td>${sortedBooking.newDate}</td>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                            <td><a href="/booking/edit/${sortedBooking.id}">Edit booking</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:when>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </table>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

    </section>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No time to flesh this into a potential answer but look up attr val selectors in CSS; set styles based on attribute values. I imagine it does exactly what you're looking for.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: We'd need to see a representative sample of output HTML.

Comment: Thank you! @TylerH It works now.